# Spring Security HTTP POSTMAN - Login - Status 405 - Method Not Allowed

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, java-8, localhost

Having build a small application utilising spring security. I tried to see if it is possible to log in with POSTMAN.

The problem is that I was getting a 405 error method not allowed.

The Url that I am using to post the request for login is /authenticateTheUser.

Posting the form to /authenticateTheUser, works fine.

I would like an advice to see if it is possible to achieve a login via POSTMAN.

```
<form action="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/authenticateTheUser" 
                          method="POST">
```

URL that I am using on POSTMAN -> http://dev.security.com/authenticatetheUser?username=mary&password=12345

I am aware that I am not passing a csrf token. I am trying first to solve the 405 issue.

```
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/").permitAll() 
            .antMatchers("/manager").hasRole("manager")
            .antMatchers("/user/**").hasRole("user")
            .antMatchers("/admin/**").hasRole("admin")
            .and()
            .formLogin()
                .loginPage("/showLoginPage")
                .loginProcessingUrl("/authenticateTheUser")
            .successHandler(customAuthenticationSuccessHandler)
                .permitAll()
            .and()
            .logout()
            .permitAll()
            .and()
                .exceptionHandling()
                .accessDeniedPage("/access-denied");
}
```

Comment: Hey,

405 - Method not allowed status code means that you are using a HTTP method which is not allowed to be sent to given url. Are you sending a POST request?

Comment: @AdrianGrzywaczewski, Hi Adrian, since the form is sending a post request, I am sending a post request as well. Is that incorrect?

Comment: Sorry, I might have misunderstood your question.
It is me just guessing now but when you are logging in through a form can you inspect that in the network tab? Just to make sure that an OPTIONS request is not being sent prior to the POST ?

Comment: @AdrianGrzywaczewski I can verify that is only the POST request. But What I found out is that I am getting
Request URL: http://dev.security.com/authenticateTheUser
Request Method: POST
Status Code: 302 
Shall I assume that spring redirects afterwards to a get Http method, and does not send a response on successful login?

Comment: how do you verify that only POST has been sent?

Comment: @AdrianGrzywaczewski does this link help ? https://ibb.co/F43BMfB

Answer (score 0):

first of all your spring security configuration is correct, as the login form works.

now it is the POSTMAN request you sent is not appropriate for your spring security configuration ...the reason is Spring Security is expecting an HTTP POST request, which contains username and password in the BODY. And you are sending a POST request did not POST the username and password in the BODY, instead you are posting in the URL, like an HTTP GET request.

to make it work, just change your POSTMAN request with URL  http://dev.security.com/authenticatetheUser
but, put the username and password in the BODY as form data...

Comment: I have tried that as well, did not work 
I have used BODY, form-data and added username, password as the parameters.
The issue is that it does not allow a post request generally. Image -> https://ibb.co/mSvSFHn

Comment: Did you ever solve this? I am having a similar issue with POST, PUT and PATCH